# How to move thousands of pictures within a site's folders?

Tags: php, web

I have a site with thousands of posts. Each post got 0-4 pictures. The pictures are in a folder system. Now I need to move all the pictures into another folder system with different hierarchy logic.

I could easily write a PHP code for this, but I guess that I can't succesfully run a file with that amount of to do. So how can I run a php file like this long enough, or what are the other possibilities?

Comment: I'm not sure why `copy()` wouldn't work for thousands of files... the server is doing all the work - not the PHP. Also, we're going to need some more information to help you.

Comment: Write the file but execute it on the commandline. There is no execution limit, so you can just let it run.

Comment: You could even use `exec('mv ' . $file1 . " " . $file2);`

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787485/recursive-function-for-copy-of-multilevel-folder-is-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write it in PHP because PHP - on the command-line - has no execution time limit. It will run endlessly if the script takes that long.

Contact your hoster for shell access.